# Access Select query values into variables

Tags: sql, vb.net

I'm trying to create a project app, in said app i have a database to store data that the user inserts which i later use for various things.
I'm trying to get the value for the Weight and Height from the DB and im currently using this code:

```
Sub load()
    Dim weight As Double
    Using getData = New OleDbCommand("SELECT TOP 1 Weight FROM Data WHERE ID_User = @ID_User ORDER BY id DESC", conn)
        getData.Parameters.Add("ID_User", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = My.Settings.currentUserID
        If conn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then conn.Open()

        weight = getData.ExecuteScalar
    End Using

    Dim height As Integer
    Using getData = New OleDbCommand("SELECT TOP 1 Height FROM Data WHERE ID_User = @ID_User ORDER BY id DESC", conn)
        getData.Parameters.Add("ID_User", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = My.Settings.currentUserID
        If conn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then conn.Open()

        height = getData.ExecuteScalar
    End Using
End Sub
```

This works fine but im trying to reduce my code, is there a way to select multiple fields values in a single select query?

**Example:**

```
SELECT TOP 1 Weight, Height FROM Data WHERE ID_User = @ID_User ORDER BY id DESC
```

I already tried to use the example code but its just returning me the weight value twice for some unknown reason.

Comment: yes, absolutely. check out this example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/retrieving-data-using-a-datareader

Comment: Scalar is designed to return a single value when invoked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [@Jeremy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/314507/jeremy) and [@ParrishHusband](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1316856/parrish-husband) for helping me i managed to solve the problem, if anyone needs the solution this is how i did it:

```
Sub load()
        Dim weight As Double
        Dim height As Integer

        Using getData = New OleDbCommand("SELECT TOP 1 Weight, Height FROM Data WHERE ID_User = @ID_User ORDER BY id DESC", conn)
            getData.Parameters.Add("ID_User", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = My.Settings.currentUserID
            If conn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then conn.Open()

            Dim reader As OleDbDataReader = getData.ExecuteReader

            If reader.HasRows Then
                While reader.Read
                    weight = reader.GetString(0)
                    height = reader.GetString(1)
                End While
            Else
                MsgBox("No rows found")
            End If
            reader.Close()
        End Using
        MsgBox(weight & ", " & height)
End Sub
```

Comment: Connections need to be disposed. You didn't even close it!

Comment: Whenever I see this `If conn.State =` I know there is a problem. Connection should be declared in the method where they are used.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know, i removed the if and replaced it with a conn.open and conn.close when i need it.

Comment: Use a Using block for the connection. Dispose means to call .Dispose so unmanaged resources can be released. Using blocks will do this for you. The New keyword needs to be local for this.